# How to use ggplot2's geom_dotplot() with symmetrically spaced and separated dots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having a problem symmetrically placing the dots in `geom_dotplot` when `stackratio` is greater than 1.  With `stackratio = 1`, the dots are symmetrically placed above the ticks marks.  With `stackratio > 1`, the dots are shifted left.  Is there a way to keep the dots symmetrically placed while creating space between the dots?

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(2018, 2021, 1), 15), 
                   y = sample(seq(3, 5, .125), 60, 
                   replace = T))

ggplot(data, aes(factor(x), y)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackratio = 1)

ggplot(data, aes(factor(x), y)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackratio = 2)
```

Comment: And it looks like things move to the right when using numbers < 1.  I don't remember if this is how it has always worked or if this is something new.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug. I've provided some details below, bit might be worth [filing an issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues). Feel free to include the details I've provided below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the [makeContext.dotstackGrob](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/4beefa1fa985bebb5b3357efeacc7b83b82c784c/R/grob-dotstack.r#L25) function. It calculates the offsets for each point with

```
xpos <- xmm + dotdiamm * (x$stackposition * x$stackratio + (1 - x$stackratio) / 2)
```

but for the life of me, I cannot see why the `(1 - x$stackratio) / 2` part is there. Without it, everyything seems to lineup OK. If I change that line to

```
xpos <- xmm + dotdiamm * x$stackposition * x$stackratio
```

and test with the sample data, I get

```
ggplot(data, aes(factor(x), y)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackratio = 1)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data, aes(factor(x), y)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackratio = .5)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data, aes(factor(x), y)) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", stackratio = 2)
```

[image]

So maybe this counts a a bug report? Not sure what else to test